# JDK fatal error when launching Pentaho spoon on CentOS

Tags: java, pentaho

I've just installed a centOS and put pentaho on it.

When I launch spoon.sh (PDI 4.4) I have this error

> /home/xxx/Bureau/data-integration
>   WARN  10-04 18:14:46,513 - Unable to load Hadoop Configuration from "file:///home/joris/Bureau/data-integration/plugins/pentaho-big-data-plugin/hadoop-configurations/mapr". For more information enable debug logging.
>   INFO  10-04 18:14:46,685 - Pentaho Data Integration - Connexion... file:///tmp/spoon_c318b172-a1f9-11e2-a78b-efa532dd0cb0.log
>
> #
>    A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>   #
>     SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000320480e00c, pid=3295, tid=140101661157120
>   #
>    JRE version: 6.0_41-b02
>    Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.14-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
>    Problematic frame:
>    C  [ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+0xe00c]
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as:
>    /home/xxx/Bureau/data-integration/hs_err_pid3295.log
>   #
>    If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>      http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
>    ./spoon.sh: line 163:  3295 Abandon                 (core dumped) "$_PENTAHO_JAVA" $OPT $STARTUP -lib $LIBPATH "${1+$@}"
>   [xxx@xxx-pentaho data-integration]$ java -version java version
>   "1.6.0_41" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_41-b02) Java
>   HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.14-b01, mixed mode)
>   [xxx@xxx-pentaho data-integration]$ clear
>
> [xxx@xxx-pentaho data-integration]$ ./spoon.sh -v
>   /home/xxx/Bureau/data-integration WARN  10-04 18:22:28,889 - Unable
>   to load Hadoop Configuration from
>   "file:///home/xxx/Bureau/data-integration/plugins/pentaho-big-data-plugin/hadoop-configurations/mapr".
>   For more information enable debug logging. INFO  10-04 18:22:28,904 -
>   Pentaho Data Integration - Connexion...
>   file:///tmp/spoon_d69c761f-a1fa-11e2-81c8-bb0cb3f99e89.log
>   #
>    A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>   #
>     SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000320480e00c, pid=3393, tid=139688929707776
>   #
>    JRE version: 6.0_41-b02
>    Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.14-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
>    Problematic frame:
>    C  [ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+0xe00c]
>   #
>    An error report file with more information is saved as:
>    /home/xxx/Bureau/data-integration/hs_err_pid3393.log
>   #
>    If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>      http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
>    ./spoon.sh: line 163:  3393 Abandon                 (core dumped) "$_PENTAHO_JAVA" $OPT $STARTUP -lib $LIBPATH "${1+$@}"

I tried to change jdk, I tried with differents Sun JDK and Open JDK and I still got this problem
I tried some stuff that I found on internet but It doesn't work (those commands below)

```
ulimit -c unlimited
./spoon.sh -XX:-UseCompressedOops
```

Answer (score 6):

I know this is after the fact, but I just ran into this problem on centos with Java 7 and fixed it by doing the following:

Disable the welcome screen in ~/.kettle/.spoonrc

ShowWelcomePageOnStartup=N

Source: http://forums.pentaho.com/archive/index.php/t-81923.html

Answer (score 1):

Basically, just start your spoon.sh with this command:

```
$ export OPT="-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/dev/null" ./spoon.sh
```

[Example of a solution here](https://jira.talendforge.org/browse/TDI-24139).

Answer (score 0):

After many changes of JDK I installed (again) the sun jdk 1.6 64bit and defined the java path

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_43"
```

Now it works. I don't have the fatal error anymore, but now i have some errors when I launch the BIServer

**EDIT: Problem resolved by puting chmod -R 777 on the file data-integration

New problem: spoon.sh works when I launch it as root user (super user) but I still got the problem with normal user
Another problem: Even if I launch it as root, when I close it it gives me the fatal error again